# Problem with using the dots ("...") argument through multiple function layers

Tags: r, function, import, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to use the dots-argument of R-functions for a data import function. The function should  take a list of file paths `data_list` and accept further arguments to pass on to an internally used `fread()` function. It should import the specified files and bind them together into a dataframe. The output is saved to the global environment.

Examples and thoughts so far:

I have a folder "test1", containing one file and a folder "test2", containing multiple files. The files are .txt files with the same internal structure (in this case 4 lines of useless header and 4 lines of data), something like this:

```
this is
a header
with some text
that should be ignored when importing
1;2;3;4
2;2;4;2
3;4;3;2
4;2;3;1
```

I generate my lists:

```
data_list_1 <- list.files(path = "./test1", 
                          recursive = TRUE, 
                          pattern = "*.txt", 
                          full.names = TRUE)

data_list_2 <- list.files(path = "./test2", 
                          recursive = TRUE, 
                          pattern = "*.txt", 
                          full.names = TRUE)
```

On a single file case, passing arguments to `fread()` works:

```
data_import_test_1 <- function(data_list, ...) {
  .GlobalEnv$test_import <- fread(file = data_list, ...)
}

# imagine i have a fileset where i need to skip the first 4 rows when
# importing (data_list_1 contains a single file path)

data_import_test_1(data_list = data_list_1, skip = 4)

# output created is a dataframe of the specified file 
# without the first 4 rows
```

But now i want to import multiple files at once with `fread()` and attach them together with `rbind()` so i wanted to wrap it inside `lapply()` like this:

```
data_import_test_2 <- function(data_list, ...) {
  .GlobalEnv$test_import <- do.call(what = rbind,
                                    args = lapply(data_list,
                                                  function(x, ...) fread(x, ...)))
}

# imagine i have multiple files of the same format as the single file 
# from the import above and data_list_2 contains all of them

data_import_test_2(data_list = data_list_2, skip = 4)

# output created still contains the rows i wanted to skip, 
# the skip = 4 argument doesnt reach fread()
```

Does anyone have ideas how to handle the handover without having to do hardcode it into the function arguments? I will use my function on segmented datasets from different sources that will need different inputs into fread. This means i would really like to have my function dynamically hand over whatever i need to feed into fread.

I really appreciate everyone having a look at this, thank you in advance!

I know that i could hardcode the parameter into my function like this:

```
data_import_test_2 <- function(data_list, fread_skip) {
  .GlobalEnv$test_import <- do.call(what = rbind,
                                    args = lapply(data_list,
                                                  function(x, fread_skip = fread_skip) 
                                                      fread(x, skip = fread_skip)))
}
```

I will want to use other arguments of `fread` for different sets of data and i do not want to have to include them all into my function arguments as it will make for a lot of clutter and reduced readability.

Comment: I think you need to pass `...` as an argument to `lapply`, in addition to specifying `...` in the function definition. Its a difference between using the variables in `...` from the parent function and specifying a child function that accepts dots.

Comment: I believe that `lapply(data_list, function(x, ...) fread(x, ...), ...)` should work; or even shorter `lapply(data_list, fread, ...)`.

Comment: And please don't assign in the global environment. That is only very very rarely a good solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try it out! Missed out on the possibility of another ...-connector in lappy

Comment: @JanvanderLaan What would you rather use? I am still quite new to R and always thankful for tips and tricks!

Comment: Instead of assigning in the global environment, the function should return the data, and when you call the function assign the result to a variable. That way it is explicit and clear from the code what the result of the function is.

Comment: Just return the result so that the user can do `data <- import_test(...)`. So in you short exampel that would be to remove the `.GlobalEnv$test_import <-` and make the `do.call` the last line in your function.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and quick help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `...` from the parent function into the child function using `lapply(x, function(.x, ...) {do_something(.x, ...)}, ...)`

For example, this will work:

```
sum_list_elements <- function(x, ...) {
    lapply(x, function(.x, ...) {
        sum(.x, ...)
    }, ...)
}
sum_list_elements(list(c(1,2,3,NA), c(4,5,6,NA)))
sum_list_elements(list(c(1,2,3,NA), c(4,5,6,NA)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

And this will not:

```
sum_list_elements_broken <- function(x, ...) {
    lapply(x, function(.x, ...) {
        sum(.x, ...)
    })
}
sum_list_elements_broken(list(c(1,2,3,NA), c(4,5,6,NA)))
sum_list_elements_broken(list(c(1,2,3,NA), c(4,5,6,NA)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: So in my case, I would have to use the "..." argument in both my do.call() and lapply()? Trying it out now! Thanks for helping me out!

EDIT: do.call() doesn't need nor want my "..." argument, but with inserting it into lapply() everything works fine.

Comment: That's right, you pass the dots into `lapply`, not `do.call`. Passing the dots to `do.call` is telling R to `rbind` the `...` parameters to the end of the dataframe, which is not what you want. `lapply` and other functions like it allow you to pass "constant" parameters to every call. For example `lapply(1:10, \`+\`, 4)` will add the constant 4 to each number 1:10 (this is not an efficient way to do this, just demonstrating a concept).